# Select rows which have the maximum values of column A for unique entries in column B

Tags: sql

I'm not sure how to even phrase this question.

Say i have a table like this:

```
a   0.1
a   0.2
a   0.3
b   0.1
b   0.4
b   0.9
c   0.1
c   0.6
```

I want to see the maximum values of column B for each of the entries in column A, i.e.

```
a   0.3
b   0.9
c   0.6
```

How do i create a query to give me this?

Comment: With GROUP BY and MAX.

Comment: Using GROUP BY? `select col1, max(col2) from tab group by col1`

Answer (score 2):

Use `group by` statement and `max` aggregation function:

```
select 
    column_A, 
    max(column_B) as column_B
from your_table
group by column_A
```

Notice, when you're using grouping of results every expression in select list should be either in list specified in `group by` or a result of applying some aggregation function (`max` in this case).